# Does Turnitin match my paper against sources found after I submitted by paper?

Tags: plagiarism

I have to submit my dissertation through Turnitin. I am planning on publishing the dissertation on my website a few days after submitting it through Turnitin so future employers can see what kind of work I produce.

I was wondering if posting it online after submitting it through Turnitin would cause any problems? The Turnitin content scrapers would find the disseration online after I submitted it through Turnitin so would it appear on the Turnitin similarity report and affect the similarity score?

**TL;DR**: I post the dissertation on the internet AFTER submitting it through Turnitin. Would it show up on my similarity report?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't wait until the school finish checking your dissertation through Turnitin and then put it on your website?

Answer (score 5):

The Turnitin settings allow for checking either when submitted or on the due date. It depends on which of these options were selected by whoever is administrating the submissions

Answer (score 5):

The worst that could happen is that Turnitin finds your thesis, is too dumb to realize that these documents are the same, and flags that there is a 100% overlap. In which case a human will look at the situation, realize that the two are the same document, and everyone moves on with their lives.

In other words, nothing to worry about. A large number of people post their theses on their websites. So this is acceptable practice, and if Turnitin can't recognize this, then that's their problem, not yours.

Answer (score 1):

Both the submitted dissertation and the website version are under your name, presumably. If so, the consequence of Turnitin findings high levels of overlap will be obvious to any employer or are easily explained.

> Scenario 1: Turnitin report: 100% overlap between dissertation by Tagatose dos Santos and material on tagatose.com.

I'm not sure that employers will worry as they can see that the dissertation's author and the blog owner is one and the same person . Journals may consider this a breach of the [Ingelfinger Rule](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199111073251910), but you'll need to check with the journal.

Things will be a little more difficult to explain if you're publishing your blog under a pseudonym or if you wish retain anonymity (in which case, even publishing your dissertation in full is questionable):

> Scenario 2: Turnitin report: 100% overlap between dissertation by Tagatose dos Santos and material on thesecretbiologist.com.